# MAAS with external DHCP TFTP time out

Tags: maas, pxe, tftp

I'm trying to get MAAS up and running, and I've installed the control node without `maas-dhcp` or `maas-dns` since I already have another DHCP server. I've set up the `next-server` attribute in my DHCP config to point to the MAAS control node, and the filename to "pxelinux.0". The setup is working with another tftp controller (Foreman).

When I pxe boot a client to try and enlist it in MAAS, it sees the DHCP server and gets the MAAS controller address, but times out looking for a tftp server. I've checked mass-pserv logs and it doesn't show any attempted connections. I've also attempted to connect from another machine with `tftp connect *maas-address*` but it gives me a `unknown host` error. I think the mass tftp server is not accepting connections or not running, but I'm not sure why.

Does `maas-dhcp` and `maas-dns` need to be installed for python twisted tftp to work?

Comment: No you don't need maas-dhcp or maas-dns installed in this scenario.  If you tftp from somewhere else manually to your MAAS cluster controller, does it connect?  Are there any errors in the /var/log/maas/pserv.log file?

Can you see the pserv process running?  It contains the TFTP server for maas.

Comment: @bigjools As I mentioned in the post, pserv is both running and its log contains no connection or error messages. I'm starting to think that this may be because I'm using a non-standard (i.e. not eth0) interface as my primary (eth3). Possibly related to this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1191735)

Comment: @user187595 An idea I had is you could try running tcpdump on the interface and see if the request is even getting to the machine (and if so, how far the connection goes).